How to setup AWS AppSync Enhanced Subscription Filters w/ Lambda Resolver
I am trying to use a Lambda resolver with AppSync to setup a subscription with enhanced filtering. I am not using the VTL template or the JS function resolvers.
Here is the code for my Lambda resolver:
import { util, extensions } from '@aws-appsync/utils';

// Resolver
export const handler = async (request: any) => {

  // Resolver input
  const somePropertyName = request.arguments.somePropertyName; 


  // Define filter
  const filter = {
    'someNestedData.somePropertyName': { eq: somePropertyName }
  };

  // Convert filter to AppSync subscription filter format and set it
  extensions.setSubscriptionFilter(util.transform.toSubscriptionFilter(filter));

  // Return null to allow subscription
  return null;
}


I get this error when I call a subscription from the client
"errors": [
{
"message": "Connection failed: {"errors":[{"errorType":"TypeError","message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setSubscriptionFilter')"}]}"
}
]
}

It's not even clear to me if Lambda resolvers can be used to setup enhanced filtering as the AWS docs all show VTL/CTX implementations and AWS support was clueless.
Any help is greatly appretiated.
